# Issue regarding a for loop based off an Access table

Tags: python, sql

Essentially what is supposed to happen is it takes from a database table some information containing IDs. In the condition that one of the input.text() elements are found on the Database as one of the IDs, I expect it to run X, but instead bypasses and runs Y

```
`DBConnect = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=C:\\A\\B\\C;')
    DBSelect = DBConnect.cursor()
    DBSelect.execute("select * from ...)
    Row = DBSelect.fetchall()
    Update = False
    for field in Row:
        Appointment_ID = field[0]
        print(Appointment_ID)
        Selected_ID = self.ui.input.text()
        Selected_ID = str(Selected_ID)
        print(Selected_ID, "this is selected")
        print(Update)

        if Appointment_ID == Selected_ID:
            Update = True

    print(Update, "this is update")
    if Update == True: 
        run X
    else:
        run Y`
```

here are the print outs that produce on a run of this code when I input 141, and as you can see it does not produce an Update = True output

139,
141 this is selected,
False,
140,
141 this is selected,
False,
141,
141 this is selected,
False,
False this is update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug. Update == True should be Update = True, inside the loop

Comment: Thanks for the response - however it doesn't seem the replacement to a single '=' has had much effect. Instead it produces this syntax error. `if Update = True: 
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It's the other Update == True that you need to change, the one *inside the loop*

Comment: I've made the changes - yet it still bypasses and runs condition Y when I expect it to run X

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in debug and watching the variables change??

Comment: Brad, I am a complete idiot. It turns out Selected_ID was an str whilst Appointment_ID was an int (Autonumber on the Database) - I've just amended this. Sorry for using your time so trivially, thanks for the help on the syntax area regardless.